# Grails spring security alternative for deprecated SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I am developing a grails application where I need to fiddle with the Session variables to implement Custom Spring Security authentication and need to set the following-

```
request.session[SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY] =
            TextEscapeUtils.escapeEntities(username)
```

Now this key comes from `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY`
which is now deprecated. Can you please suggest me an alternative for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes I have faced the same problem. And it has a very simple alternative-

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils;
```

Now use `SpringSecurityUtils.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY` this will work and is not deprecated.